# Difference in ng-repeat between 1.1.1 and 1.1.5

Tags: angularjs

I am using angular 1.1.5. In my code I am reading a json object with an array of objects in it. Every object has a property representing a list of labels as space-delimited list. I am counting occurences in a custom filter and output the results with ng-repeat. Nothing complicated.

But there seems to be a difference between 1.1.1 and 1.1.5.

My ng-repeat expression:

`(key, value) in (r.items | extractLabels:'labels')`

It works with angular 1.1.1. See http://jsfiddle.net/waxolunist/vQyCn/

It does not work with angular 1.1.5. See http://jsfiddle.net/waxolunist/vQyCn/8/

I get following error: `Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed.`

But it works with following modification to the code:

`(key, value) in (r.items | extractLabels:'labels') track by $id(key)`

See http://jsfiddle.net/waxolunist/vQyCn/9/

I read about the `track by` expression in this document (http://code.angularjs.org/1.1.5/docs/api/ng.directive:ngRepeat) and it works, but I totally don't understand it.

Can someone please explain to me, what am I doing here? And am I doing it right? And why is this difference?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In newer version of angular it's not allowing duplication in list/object, so to remove this duplication from object you can differentiate all item by referring  them using unique-id (track by $id(key) ). I.e. what you are doing is right to figure out the duplication error.

Comment: I think I can follow your explanation. Thx